# Using JQuery to hide parent li based on child div background-color

Tags: jquery

I am using a cms that does not allow changes to the html.

It creates upcoming events on a sidebar and adds a colored div before each type of event to categorize them. I want to use JQuery to only show one of the categories on certain pages.

Here is the code they generate:

```
<ul class="upcomingEvents">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
    <div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color:#f8546f;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;First</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sunday</i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color: #000;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;Second</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Friday</i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color: #F16FCC;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;Third</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Wednesday</i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color: #F16FCC;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;Fourth</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Monday</i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to only show 'third' and 'fourth'  event from this code, but I'm not provided with classes or ids. My thought was to identify that category by the background-color of the child div in those li's. Hide all li's on page load. Then tell jquery to only show the desired li's.

I would want to resulting code to look as follows:

```
<ul class="upcomingEvents">
    <li style="display: none; ">
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color:#f8546f;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;First</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sunday</i>
    </li>
    <li style="display: none; ">
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color: #000;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;Second</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Friday</i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color: #F16FCC;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;Third</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Wednesday</i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><div style="display:inline;width:3px;height:1em;background-color: #F16FCC;">&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;Fourth</a>
        <br>
        <i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Monday</i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried using this code but with no success.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".upcomingEvents li").hide();
    if ($(".upcomingEvents div").css("backgroundColor") == "rgb(241, 111, 204)") $(this).show();
});​
```

What am I doing wrong?

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the `eq()` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $li = $(".upcomingEvents li")
    $li.hide();
    $li.eq(2).show() // the third 'li' element
    $li.eq(3).show() 
});​
```

With your current solution, you can use the `each` method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".upcomingEvents li").hide();
    $(".upcomingEvents li div").each(function(){
        if ( $(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(241, 111, 204)" ) {
           $(this).closest('li').show()
        }
    })
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7wFK/212/)**

Comment: That does work for this example, but the amount and order of 'li' elements are constantly changing.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem like a great solution but somehow it still won't work. I used jfiddle to test it.. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/E7wFK/206/

Comment: @MendyB You are welcome, sorry there was a typo, try this http://jsfiddle.net/E7wFK/212/

Comment: It worked! Apparently the code was missing a ')' and a ; Here is the edited code:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".upcomingEvents li").hide();
    $(".upcomingEvents div").each(function() {
        if ($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(248, 84, 111)"){
            $(this).closest('li').show();
        }
    });
});

Comment: @MendyB It had an extra `)` in the if statement.

Answer (score -1):

I'd debug and see what `$(".upcomingEvents div").css("backgroundColor")` is stored as. I doubt it would be `"rgb(241, 111, 204)"`.

It's probably the equivalent color but in this `format: #ffffff`

Comment: yeah he can add a console.log to log the exact value or even better convert it to a specific format to be always sure

Comment: `css` method  returns an `rgb` value.

Comment: It seems to recognize the hex and the rgb format, but not with my code above. for example the following does work. $(".upcomingEvents div").css("backgroundColor", "#F16FCC");